# UI tests in Azure pipelines displays error cannot find chrome binary using node js

Tags: node.js, azure-pipelines

I am trying to run UI tests in Azure devops pipelines and I created the yaml file and added the command to run UItests on chrome, but gets an error "WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary"
I am using node js code

Here is the YAML file:

```
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  name: 'Default'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    npm run build
  displayName: 'npm install and build'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'install'
    customCommand: 'iocContainer'
  displayName: 'npm iocContainer'

- task: CmdLine@2
  inputs:
    script: '.\runUITest.bat "@RecieveOnlineOrder"'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> WebDriverError: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary

The problem seems to be that the chrome driver cannot find the chrome.exe file.

Since you are using the self-hosted agent, you need to make sure you have installed Chrome on your local machine firstly. If only the chrome driver is installed, you will face this issue.

You could also try to update the chrome driver to the latest.

If you have install the Chrome, you could check the file path of chrome.exe.

As per [the ChromeDriver - Requirements](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#requirements):

[image]

On the other hand, this issue may be related to the version of chrome, this is [an open ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/1170486/selenium-ui-test-can-no-longer-find-chrome-binary.html) with similar issues, you could refer to it.

You could try to run the following script and check if it could work:

```
npm i chromedriver --chromedriver_version=LATEST --save-dev
```

Comment: Many thanks for you, I tried this command and it works,

Comment: I added task in Yaml file `- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'i chromedriver --chromedriver_version=LATEST --save-dev'
  displayName: 'npm chromedriver'`